# Google Maps API with Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering if anyone out there has worked with Google Maps API with Rails 3. I'm looking for launching ideas, gems, plugins etc.

I played around with [ym4r-gm plugin](http://www.killswitchcollective.com/articles/65_google_maps_on_rails) for several hours today, with not much luck. Have you played with this API on rails 3 yet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

YM4R doesn't offer much beyond a few wrappers of the API functions. I used YM4R for a while but then ditched it in favour of using the Google Maps API directly (from JavaScript). Perhaps it's an option you could consider too?

Answer (score 25):

Just fyi, I made https://rubygems.org/gems/gmaps4rails which is a useful wrapper with several options.

Answer (score 6):

Cartographer plug-in supports Rails 3+ ,

It has been re-written to work for huge number of markers and clusters

it integrates pretty well with google maps v3 and rails 3 , http://grati.la/cartorbflw

Comment: The link above was forked from the original, and is missing one key line the README document. I suggest cloning this instead [https://github.com/joshuamiller/cartographer/tree/master/lib/v3/cartographer] https://github.com/joshuamiller/cartographer/tree/master/lib/v3/cartographer

Answer (score 2):

there is GMaps v3 gem for Rails 3 (also 2.3) called [BHM Google Maps](http://github.com/YouthTree/bhm-google-maps) didn't have much luck with it, but you can give it a try

Answer (score 2):

it all depends what you want to do I use this as a gem "https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails" and works wonderful I started learning rails a few days I go and I got it up and running in like 20min.

Answer (score 0):

you can always check out [ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) for current status of gems because some become inactive over time.Also, decide which gems to use depending on application.
Now [GMaps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) is currently widely used.