# Cartographer plugin rendering odd map

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is an image to describe the problem:

[image]

So I am using https://github.com/parolkar/cartographer (which at this stage is only available as a plugin), and am getting the unusual map rendering as seen above. Everything looks fine with regard to the icons locations, etc.. but when I click on them I get funky info boxes (with the correct information).

Here is the code I'm using to generate the map and info boxes:

```
@map = Cartographer::Gmap.new( 'map')
@map.zoom = :bound
@icon = Cartographer::Gicon.new()
@map.icons <<  @icon

@count = 0
@numrecords.times do 
    markername = "marker#{@count}"
    markername = Cartographer::Gmarker.new(:name=> "Business#{@count}", :marker_type => "Building",
                         :position => [@lat[@count], @long[@count]],
                         :info_window_url => "/bio/#{@branch_id[@count]}", :icon => @icon)

    @map.markers << markername
    @count += 1
    end
```

from controller as well:

```
def bio
    @branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
    render :layout => false 
end
```

and the bio view file

```
<%= link_to "#{@branch.name}", branch_path %><br />
<%= @branch.business.name %><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bootstrap issue, not a cartographer issue.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1552

NOTE: Just in case anyone reads this, I would suggest gmaps4rails over cartographer as this is a newer gem with support.