# Learning geokit-rails3

Tags: google-maps, geokit

I'm searching for complete explanations about how to use geokit-rails3. I've found loads for rails2 but not for rails3. Does any of you have a simple and complete tutorial about how to display a google map on Rails3, from A to Z ? 
Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geokit (and geokit-rails3) can be thought of as geocoding utility libraries, useful for finding and storing the locations of model instances and for performing location-based searches, but they do not include mapping support.

For Google Maps mapping in rails 3 [there are a few choices, but no clear winner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557174/google-maps-api-with-rails-3-0). At the moment, most end up just using the Google Maps javascript API version 3 directly. I found [Google's Maps API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) very clear and easy to use.